# Angular Guard canActivate not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a situation in canActivate where I have to call two api's to return true. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong in the code?

**Route:**

```
{
  path: 'botPage',
  component: BotPageComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: { userType: ['User', 'Admin'], permissionByPass: true }
}
```

**AuthGuard:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Resolve, Router, ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private _route: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  // autheticate user logged in and router
  canActivate(
    act_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt_token');
    if (token) {
      if (!this._auth.isTokenExpired(token)) {
        if (act_route.data.userType) {
          return this.checkUserType(act_route);
        } else { }
      } else {
        this._auth.userOut();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      this._auth.userOut();
      return false;
    }
  }

  checkUserType(act_route: any): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._auth.checkUserType().pipe(
      map(
        res => {
          if (act_route.data.userType.includes(res)) {
            if (!act_route.data.permissionByPass && res !== 'SuperAdmin') {
              return this.checkAccess(act_route);
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            this._route.navigate(['403']);
            return false;
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }

  checkAccess(act_route): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._auth.chkacs().pipe(
      map(
        chkres => {
          console.log('api called');
          if (chkres.data[act_route.data.accessPage]) {
            return true;
          } else {
            this._route.navigate(['403']);
            return false;
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The error I am getting by tslint is

*Type 'Observable>' is not assignable to
 type 'Observable'.*

The expected behaviour is that the page should navigate only after the response of second api. But the page is not getting navigated. I have tried multiple ways, but by this way, I at least have got the api's to hit the server. Where am I getting wrong here?

Comment: try to use flatmap operator instead of map in the checkUserType since you here chaining observable

Comment: can you provide a example

Comment: use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) to flatten and switch to inner observable.